# Automatically Detect When a User Verifies Email

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, email-validation

I have a website built with the Laravel framework. When a user creates a new account, they are immediately taken to their dashboard with a message telling them to check their email for a verification link. All buttons on the dashboard are disabled until they verify their email.

I would like the dashboard page to automatically detect when a user verifies their email, and then immediately enable the buttons without the user having to manually refresh the page after verification. How can I do this?

Comment: For having the back-end push updates to the browser, the technology you're probably looking for is called "web sockets".

Comment: listen to the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified` event, and broadcast it to the frontend via websockets

Comment: I was just about to write the exact same answer @Salim provided here. This is the way to go.

Comment: I have never heard of/used websockets before.... I already have an event listener set up for `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified` to send a welcome email, so that step is complete. What would the code look like for implementing websockets to achieve my desired functionality?

Comment: It is pretty much complex concept but [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting) makes it breeze. You should add some code into your [question](http://sscce.org/). Also, read this great article that will help you making [perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: I will definitely give that a read. As for my code, the reason I didn’t provide any is because I’m not exactly sure what code people would need to solve my question.

Comment: That is answered in those two links I left you there.

Answer (score -3):

One way would be to have an API endpoint where you can add user information (id, email, bla bla) and it returns either true or false. Make a request to that endpoint every so often (maybe use some form of backoff such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff like if it fails try after one second, then if it fails try after ten seconds, ... ) to avoid overloading the backend.

keep the UI disabled until you get a positive response from the backend.

that being said, you might need to add this check on every action a user can take depending on business requirement because you can never (completely) trust the client